# Ruler append element every 5 pixels to fill it's width

Tags: jquery

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7afPQ/

I wanted to try building a ruler from scratch today starting at 0 then append a few divs every 5 & 10 pixels to fill it's containers width.

My fiddle shows an example of what I've been trying to accomplish.

Here's an HTML example.

```
<div class='ruler'>
    <div class="tickLabel" style="left: 0px;">0</div>
    <div class="tickMinor" style="left: 5px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMajor" style="left: 10px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMinor" style="left: 15px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMajor" style="left: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMinor" style="left: 25px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMajor" style="left: 30px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMinor" style="left: 35px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMajor" style="left: 40px;"></div>
    <div class="tickMinor" style="left: 45px;"></div>
    <div class="tickLabel" style="left: 50px;">50</div>
    and so on...
</div>
```

I've been trying to wrap it all in a single function here using window onload resize. I know what I want to do, but I don't really understand how this would be done using JQuery.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    $('.ruler').html("").append( ticks );
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use jQuery there is a .resize() (https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function which you can use to catch all window resize events:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    ....
});
```

To create a ruler you can use a for loop with switch inside (for example), which based on the current tick (step) will add a specific class to it. To get a number of ticks/iterations you can check the width of container with the .innerWidth() (https://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) function and divide it by 5 (5px is your single tick's length).

After creating the ruler creating function you will probably call it in two places:
inside document ready block, to create and show it when page is ready, and inside the window resize block mentioned above (so the ruler is always spannning the full width of container).

Here is a example based on your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7afPQ/2/

Comment: Never seen or used a switch case statement before. I'll have to read up on it. Thanks!

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/7afPQ/3/ is an updated version with if - else if - else test in place of the switch. If you prefer.

Comment: I've been having trouble getting the location of the label listed on the ruler. http://jsfiddle.net/7afPQ/4/

Comment: The get correct labels on the ruler you could use for example the iteration counter. If you want to get number of ticks use 'i', or if you want to count the pixels use 'i * 5', since every step is 5 pixels long. For example, the line 11 in your last example could be changed to: '$tick.addClass('tickLabel').html(i * 5);' - this way the major tick labels will display the number of pixels from the left side of your ruler.

Comment: It's ok. I am glad I could help you ;-).

Comment: @TV.  I added jquery's resizable widget on class .ruler. Once i start the resize and stop it the handle on the east vanishes and i dont find the ui-resizable div inside the .ruler dom. Check the code here http://jsfiddle.net/vinvik88/7afPQ/17/

Comment: I think you need to find a way to reinitialize the resize effect on your object. I don't know this plugin, so I am not sure what is the right way to do it, but here is a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/4aqmqq90/ - try to find some more informations about it in the plugin's documentation.